# How to revert a failed git-stash apply?

Tags: git

NOTE: I believe the use-case in this question is significantly different from the ones in [How to reverse apply a stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020132) and [Aborting `git stash apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242844).

I just did a `git stash apply` that, to my surprise, did not go through cleanly (i.e. conflicts were detected).

What is the cleanest way to return to the state *just before* I ran `git stash apply`?

(I wish there were a `--ff-only` option for `git stash [apply|pop]`, like there is for `git pull`, etc.)

Comment: Wouldn't a `git checkout .` + `git clean -qxdf` do?

Comment: Why do you think your use case is different from the linked ones? If you 1) had a clean work space, 2) applied the stash 3) an encountered conflicts, you should be able to return to the original state by using git reset --hard

Comment: Still need `git clean` to remove stuff that wasn't tracked in HEAD