# How to reverse apply a stash that with conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-stash, git-merge-conflict

I have seen the question [How to reverse apply a stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020132/how-to-reverse-apply-a-stash) asked by [Pat Notz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825/pat-notz). And I have tried the approved answer, but I get such an error,

```
sudo git stash show -p | git apply --reverse
    error: patch failed: app/controllers/CloudController.php:673
    error: app/controllers/CloudController.php: patch does not apply
    error: patch failed: app/controllers/CloudGcode.php:1
    error: app/controllers/CloudGcode.php: patch does not apply
```

I have to explain how I run in this situation. 
I have a stashes in my stash list, and I have do some modify in my working repository. The changes in my working repository have conflict with the stash@{0}. Then I execute the `git add .` and `sudo git stash apply` commands by fault, and it shows this info,

```
sudo git stash apply
[sudo] password for xxxx:
    Auto-merging app/controllers/CloudGcode.php
    CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/controllers/CloudGcode.php
    Auto-merging app/controllers/CloudController.php
    CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/controllers/CloudController.php
```

After the stash apply, there is conflict in my file like this,

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
            for($i = 0; $i < $textlen; $i++)
            {
                $char = $uchars[$index++];
                if($char !== 0)
                    $text = $text.chr($char);
            }
            $this->text = $text;
Log::info('LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL'.$text);
=======
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->textlen; $i++)
                $text = $text.$uchars[$index++];
            $this->text = $text;
            $this->text[$this->textlen] = 0; // Terminate string overwriting checksum
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
            $this->waitUntilAllCommandsAreParsed = true; // Don't destroy string until executed
        }
        $this->formatErrors = 0;
        return true;
    }
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
=======
```

Then I google how to revert it. I come in the question [How to reverse apply a stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020132/how-to-reverse-apply-a-stash) asked by [Pat Notz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825/pat-notz), and tried the solution of that question.
I want to know is there a way to rool back the state before execute the `sudo git stash apply`, just after or before execute `git add .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply re-stash, and then git reset (or even `git reset --hard`, provided you did stash first), as mentioned in "[Aborting `git stash apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9242872/6309)".

If you do a `reset --hard` without stashing first, you can still see your patch in `.git/refs/stash`, as described in "[Undo `git reset --hard` after `git stash pop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27431638/6309)" (by a `git stash apply` would not remove the patch from the stash anyway, like `git stash pop` does, so here you don't have to worry about that), or [you can recover it from `git fsck`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91795/6309).

> I want to roll back the state before execute the `sudo git stash apply`

Since the `git apply --reverse` does not work, it is best to get back to HEAD as I suggest above, and redo your operations.

Comment: I  want to rool back the state before execute the `sudo git stash apply`, just after or before execute `git add .`, not the HEAD.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Easier to go back to HEAD and start over here.

Comment: if go back to HEAD, mofifications between HEAD and git add . will be lost.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Not if you stash them first. Or you could simply make another clone, and `git --work-tree=/path/to/current/mangled/clone add -p .`, adding back only the pieces you want.

Comment: It's a shame, I didn't stash them.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Maybe the git fsck can help then? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109433/6309)

Comment: is seems do. I'll just have a try. Thanks for your time and enlightment.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Sure, let us (the readers) know here if you get back your data.